# How to catch errors within the Google Analytics Embed API for JS

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I am using the Google Analytics API. The website is not whitelisted for the project's client ID, so this call...

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({ container: 'login-button', clientid: 'xxx' });
```

generates an error:

> Uncaught {error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: "Not a
>   valid origin for the client: http://example.com this origin for your
>   project's client ID."}

That's perfectly normal, but I would like to catch it. Unfortunately, this call doesn't return a promise. I tried to add a listener this way:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.on('error', err => console.log('Caught it?', err));
```

But that doesn't work. Of course, I have tried try/catch and a few other ideas but I failed to find the solution.

The documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference. But it's not helpful about that matter.

I would love your help with this. Thanks :)

Comment: have you tried looking around here https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, I looked into the issues for a while :(